# How to correctly add resources in a rc file

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, resource-files

I'm working on a project I did not start and I added

```
#define IDS_SELF_UPDATE_EXIT            266
```

and

```
IDS_CONFIRM_EXIT        "Are you sure you want to quit?"
```

and I got the following error twice:

```
error RC2135: file not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which C++ compiler do you use ? Check if the encoding of your .rc file is ANSI. You can do latter by opening your .rc file with notepad, then you do File-Save As and check that "Encoding" is "ANSI" in the Save As dialog.

Comment: Why do you manually edit the file when there is a resource editor for such files?

Comment: Forget about the DIALOGEX stuff in the other stackoverflow question. It is probably totally unrelated.

Comment: The encoding was UTF-8 and changing to ANSI does the trick, but it also changes the special characters from the file to weird accented ones. I checked the older versions of the file, from when it worked, and the encoding was also UTF-8. I reverted to an older version, but it still doesn't work. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: How did you change the enconding from UTF-8 to ANSI. Which special caracters have been changed to weird ones. Give me an example.

Comment: I changed the encoding with Notepad++. "Verifică" becomes "VerificÄ", "Ieșire" becomes "IeĹźire", so on and so forth.

Comment: @Marius I haven't worked with resource files before. Had I known it isn't advised, I wouldn't have done it. Anything in particular you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to create a [stringtable resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050.aspx). The correct syntax is

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
  IDS_CONFIRM_EXIT        "Are you sure you want to quit?"
END
```

Comment: I was trying to add another string to a string table, except I was not doing it right. Instead of editing the resource file with the resource file editor VS offers, I edited it in VS, but manually, as a normal source file. Another issue I had was that the language setting of the keyboard used different encoding than the one in the resource file.

Comment: The error message you cited suggests that you placed that line at the top level of the file, outside of stringtable's `BEGIN/END` block. Is this not what happened? Also, what bearing does `IDS_SELF_UPDATE_EXIT` macro have on the situation? Why have you shown it?